# Cannot find upstart logs in syslog despite a log-priority of debug (ubuntu 13.04 & mint 16)

Tags: ubuntu, logging, syslog, upstart, linuxmint

I've set upstart log level to "debug"

```
sudo initctl log-priority debug
```

But I still cannot see anything in `/var/log/syslog`.

```
sudo initctl emit hello # no log
sudo initctl start my-broken-service # still no log
```

I've checked `rsyslog` config (in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`), and everything seems fine:

```
 *.*;auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
```

Logging works

```
 logger hello # prints hello in /var/log/syslog
```

I'm running both an ubuntu 13.04 and a mint 16 and the result is the same.

I wanted to check upstart options in grub but I couldn't find a line in grub's config matching upstart.

Any idea?

---

**Edit:** This problem also occurs on Ubuntu 13.10. On Ubuntu 12.04, the log messages appear in `/var/log/syslog`. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441748/where-are-upstart-log-messages-on-ubuntu-13-x) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a Ubuntu 13.10 system. It works as expected on a Ubuntu 12.04 system. [**Here**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372283/upstart-logs-missing) is another example of somebody who seems to be having the same problem.

Comment: I found yet another instance of this problem on Ask Ubuntu, still with no answer or leads. I posted a [**new question**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441748/where-are-upstart-log-messages-on-ubuntu-13-x) consolidating the known information and linking to all of the extant questions I could find.

Answer (score 3):

I've posted an answer to Bradd's question on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/490900/297973. Long story short, you may need to add `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` to rsyslogd's config.

Answer (score 1):

The logs are stored in /var/log/dmesg. Use the command `dmesg` or `tail /var/log/dmesg` to view them.

Comment: On my 13.X systems, the messages did not appear *anywhere* in `/var/log` and other users have reported the same.

Comment: Thanks to Matthew’s answer, I now understand what you were trying to get across here. Thanks for the help.